# Run-time error 1004, Unable to get the HLookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba

every time i run the code the error

> "run-time error 1004: Unable to get the HLookup property of the worksheetfunction class"

when i do a hlookup in an excel sheet with the same parameters,it works, it returns the value i want to.

```
Sub lookup()

Dim shift As Integer
Set myrange = Range("A1:AZ8")

shift = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup("01:30:00", myrange, 3, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try `.0625` instead of `"01:30:00"`?

Comment: You are getting that error because ti cannot find a match

Comment: hey,
yes it appears.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `WorksheetFunction` property is that it causes the code to break if it encounters an error. So use method of the `Application` object instead. For example

```
Application.HLookup(....)
```

You can also handle the error if you want. For example

```
Debug.Print Application.IfError(Application.HLookup("01:30:00", myrange, 3, False), "Not Found")
```

BTW declare `shift` As `Variant` instead of `Integer`. Also avoid naming your variables with reserved names. You can use, say, `Dim result as Variant` instead of using `Dim Shift as Variant`

Comment: when using Application.HLookup(....) the result was "error 2042". I've just changed the format type on my table on the first row to "text" as my first Hlookup argument is a string. And it worked. Thank you :)